Issues with Subscribing to Webhooks in Shopify Embedded App
I'm trying to subscribe to the orders/updated webhook from a Shopify embedded app, but I'm encountering an issue where all webhook requests are failing according to the Partner Dashboard insights. Here's what I have done so far:

Configured the shopify.app.toml file:
[[webhooks.subscriptions]]
topics = [ "orders/updated" ]
uri = "/webhooks"


Set up the POST endpoint to handle the webhook:
app.post('/webhooks', express.text({ type: '*/*' }), async (req, res) => {
  const { valid, topic, domain } = await shopify.api.webhooks.validate({
    rawBody: req.body,
    rawRequestBody: req,
    rawResponse: res,
  });

  if (!valid) {
    return res.status(400);
  }

  if (topic === 'orders/create' || topic === 'orders/updated') {
    // await this._orderRoute.syncOrdersHandler(req, res);
    console.log('Order updated');
  }
});



Despite setting this up, the Partner Dashboard shows that all webhook requests fail.
Can someone help me identify the problem and guide me on how to fix this issue?
